# Joomla PHP does not match host PHP

Tags: php, installation

I'm brand new to web dev and I've installed Joomla to my website. For whatever reason I can't do hardly anything because my php version is only 5.3 according to Joomla.

However, from my cpanel I changed the php to 5.5.

How do I get Joomla to update the php version?

Comment: Maybe look here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oops, I thought I posted there. I'll fix.